# File download is not working properly

Tags: php, file, download, file-extension

I am trying to download a file using PHP. Now the file is downloaded , but it is not getting in the original format (extension missing). I can use the downloaded  file after rename it using the original file extension. I am using the following code

```
header("Expires: 0");  
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Content-type: application/".$result['ext']);  
header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));  
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$result['file_name']); 
readfile($file);  
exit;
```

where

```
$result['ext']="rar",
$file="file path to the uploaded folder".
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to send the extension to the browser in the file name as part of your `Content-disposition` header.

For your code, you would have to change this:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$result['file_name']);
```

to:

```
$filename = $result['file_name'] . '.' . $result['ext'];
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

Comment: How can I rate you . Sorry i can't see any option here :(

Comment: You're welcome! You won't have the option to accept an answer until 15 minutes passes from when the question was asked. For more info, see [how does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)